# Can we have multiple join tables for the same pair of tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many, join

I have two tables: offers and tests.

But I need to have three join tables like, offers_tests_1, offers_tests_2, and offers_tests_3. This is because of a business requirement that an offer can have three combinations (packages) of tests.

Can we do this in Rails? For one join table, I could do it using the has_and_belongs_to_many association in the models with f.collection_select tag in the view, with :multiple => true.

Worst case, I could set up three tables tests_1, tests_2 and tests_3 with the same data. I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can**
You can do it in model when defining your relationships. Like this.

**In model Offer.rb**

```
has_many :offers_tests_1
has_many :offers_tests_2
has_many :tests, through: :offers_tests_1
has_many :tests, through: :offers_test_2
```

**in model Tests.rb**

```
has_many :offers_tests_1
has_many :offers_tests_2
has_many :offers, through: :offers_tests_1
has_many :offers, through: :offers_test_2
```

**enjoy**

Comment: I am going with this approach, but the view is still a problem. I have the following --
`<%= form_for(@offer) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :offers_tests_1 do |ot| %>
        <%= ot.collection_select(:test_id, Test.all, :id, :property, {include_hidden: false}, :multiple => true) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>`

The error I have is -- Field doesn't have a default value

Comment: not fields_for :offers_tests_1 use fields_for :tests

Comment: Where in the collection_select do I specify the association? I have three associations and three join tables. If I use fields_for :tests, Rails is inserting data into the third join table.